# How do I disable temporarily the hover of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a webpage. I created a popup that when I hover the div, the popup opens and if not, it closes.
I want to make a function that if I click on the div, the popup stay open without hover. How I can do? Thanks in advance.

I have this code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="password-lost-tooltip" onclick="blockTooltip()">Lost password?
        <span class="password-lost-tooltiptext" id="lostpasswordtooltip">LOL</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.password-lost-tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 55px;
    left: 380px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    color: grey;
}

.password-lost-tooltip:hover {
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.password-lost-tooltip .password-lost-tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 49px;
    left: 610px;
    margin-left: -60px;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.password-lost-tooltip .password-lost-tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: 57.5px;
    left: 542.5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.password-lost-tooltip:hover .password-lost-tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: You could use a `transition-delay`. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

Comment: You mean when you move the mouse off of the div that it closes?

Comment: Add a click event handler to the div to capture your click. In the callback, add a class to the div like "open", and add a CSS selector for `.open` to mimic your `:hover`. Then, add a second click handler to `body` or some far up parent container that removes the class "open" on your div so that it "closes" again. You could also do it with a single click handler on `document` or `body`, and check which element was clicked. If it was the div, add "open"; if not, remove "open".

Answer (score 1):

You can use onClick and onBlur events to set or remove a class on the div which then should be added to the css to control the visibility.

Please checkout this running example:

```js
function blockTooltip () {
  document.querySelector('.password-lost-tooltip').classList.add('showTip');
}

function hideTooltip () {
  document.querySelector('.password-lost-tooltip').classList.remove('showTip');
}
```

```css
.password-lost-tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 55px;
    left: 380px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    color: grey;
}

.password-lost-tooltip:hover {
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.password-lost-tooltip .password-lost-tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 49px;
    left: 610px;
    margin-left: -60px;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.password-lost-tooltip .password-lost-tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: 57.5px;
    left: 542.5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.password-lost-tooltip:hover .password-lost-tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.password-lost-tooltip.showTip .password-lost-tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="password-lost-tooltip" tabindex="0"
     onclick="blockTooltip()" onblur="hideTooltip()">Lost password?
        <span class="password-lost-tooltiptext" id="lostpasswordtooltip">LOL</span>
</div>
```